# procedure nopass vs plain function in fortran

Tags: oop, static, fortran

So in other languages static methods have access to static members and their visibility is limited by the class scope. In fortran, there are no static members (correct me if I'm wrong) and the method name is globally accessible so I can't even have two static methods with the same name in different classes. I consider "nopass" methods to be "static" but I'm not even sure if the term is applicable. Given the above, I don't see any difference from just plain module functions. Is there any benefit of using nopass-methods over plain functions?

Edit:

An illustration of inability to have two static methods with the same name in different classes:

```
module test_mod
  type type1
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: proc => proc1
  end type

  type type2
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: proc => proc2
  end type

contains
  subroutine proc1()
    print *, 'proc1'
  end subroutine

  subroutine proc2()
    print *, 'proc2'
  end subroutine
end module
```

Obviously, I can't just say `call proc()` now, nor can I use the class name to help the compiler pick the right method.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't even have two static methods with the same name in different classes"?

Comment: @francescalus I've updated my question

Comment: You can't `call proc` in any circumstance.  `call t1%proc` on the other hand (for `type(type1) t1`)...

Comment: @francescalus Ok, I didn't know one can do it this way. Previously I was just giving them different names and called them without object qualifiers just like plain functions. So the first advantage of nopass methods is limiting names visibility which, however, comes at a price of having a dummy uninitialized object which is at least not elegant. Any other benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider accessibility: a public type-bound procedure is accessible whenever the type is accessible.

```
module mod
  private
  type, public :: type1
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: proc
  end type

contains

  subroutine proc
  end subroutine

end module

  use mod
  type(type1) t1

  call t1%proc
  call proc  ! No, we can't call proc from mod1

end
```

Similarly, with `use <module>, only <...>`

```
module mod1
  type type1
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: proc
  end type

contains

  subroutine proc
  end subroutine

end module

module mod2
  type type2
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: proc
  end type

contains

  subroutine proc
  end subroutine

end module
```

We can avoid conflicts in the module procedure names without renaming on use association:

```
  use mod1, only : type1
  use mod2, only : type2

  type(type1) t1
  type(type2) t2

  call t1%proc
  call t2%proc    ! These aren't ambiguous

end
```

To avoid ambiguity on the procedures we'd instead have to rename:

```
  use mod1, proc1=>proc
  use mod2, proc2=>proc

  call proc1
  call proc2

end
```

There's also dynamic selection of procedure reference:

```
module mod
  type type1
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: proc=>proc1
  end type

  type, extends(type1) :: type2
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: proc=>proc2
  end type

contains

  subroutine proc1
  end subroutine

  subroutine proc2
  end subroutine

end module

use mod
class(type1), allocatable :: t

t=type1()
call t%proc  ! proc1

t=type2()
call t%proc  ! proc2

end
```

It should be noted, though, that a binding name like `t1%proc` is not the same thing as a procedure name

```
 use mod
 type(type1) t1
 call sub(proc1)    ! Where this is accessible
 call sub(t1%proc)  ! We cannot do this

contains

 subroutine sub(proc)
   procedure() proc
 end subroutine

end
```